# Logarithm plot in Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I would like to make a logarithm plot with the grid on option in excel using python. Here is my code:

```
valx = Reference(ws,(start_row, initialColumn), (countRow,initialColumn))
yaw =  Reference(ws,(start_row, initialColumn+1), (countRow,initialColumn+1))

plotpower = Series(yaw, xvalues = valx, title='Yaw PSD') 

chart = ScatterChart()
chart.add_serie( plotpower )
ws.add_chart(chart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Charts actually pretty stupid things and depend on Excel to calculate the values. Your y-series will be a set of formulae calculating the logs you need.